# Can't load files into PopART

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, haplotypenetwork

I am trying to create haplotype networks in [PopART](http://popart.otago.ac.nz/index.shtml) (Population genetics with Reticulated Trees*) which I have successfully done many times in the past.

Two weeks ago the program was working fine for me but recently I am unable to load files. What happens is that when I go to load a nexus file through the "nex" button, or through the "file/import/alignment" or "file/open" options nothing loads.

There is no error message, instead nothing happens. This occurs with both files I have recently created and with files that I have successfully loaded in the past. I've sent files to other people and everyone has been able to load the files using PopART on their computers. I am running macOS 10.15.6 and have tried turning my computer off and on as well as uninstalling and reinstalling PopART. I also thought that maybe Java wasn't up to date on my computer but I don't think PopArt runs with Java. Any help would be very appreciated!

---

PopArt builds reticulated HAplotype networks such shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @user438383, converted from comment:*

Hi, this seems like quite a niche problem that you are facing, perhaps a bug in the GUI of some kind. Although it's on-topic, I think you're unlikely to find somewhere here who can help (unless the popart devs lurk here). I would suggest emailing the authors, but they point towards the github which mostly seems to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, ill email the authors.

Answer (score 0):

PopArt have a mailing list popartusers+subscribe@googlegroups.com

If you go [here](http://popart.otago.ac.nz/contact.shtml) you can subscribe to it. This sounds like an issue with Mac compatibility. OS 10.15.6 isn't a version I understand and suspect there's a typo. Currently I believe it is OSX 12.1, thus OS10.12.1
PopArt was written for OSX10.6 and upwards. HOWEVER, there can be issues with major system upgrades so Monterey OSX12, I think was a major revision. PopArt is no longer supported so it would be sensitive to changes in Mac OS.

My suggestion is to try this on a Windows machine, if you get the same error the suspicion is there has been a small change to the input format.